# Cypress is it possible to run single test in parallel with diffrent data sets

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, cypress

I want to run a single test in parallel with different data sets.

I am storing the data set in fixures.

Comment: You can play with the [Module API](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/module-api/#cypress-run) to kick off the same spec in different processes. You question lacks details, so I have no idea what "different data sets" consists of.

Comment: for example, suppose I am testing the singing module
and in the future, I have an array of objects which contain correct login details.
now I want to test it with these login details.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to load all your data into objects from the fixtures, but you could then add each response to an array and `shift` each time inside a while loop. Your error reporting won’t be great but you should be able to process all of your data sets with minimal code duplication.
Something like this, maybe:

```
it(‘tests my data sets’, () => {
    const datasets = [dataset1, dataset2, dataset3];
    while(dataset.length > 0) {
        cy.intercept('GET', '/todos', req => req.reply(datasets.shift()));
        cy.get(‘items’).should(‘be.visible’);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But how can we execute tests with these datasets with parallelization. I want to test each dataset in parallel

Comment: Ah, right. You’d probably need to spin up docker containers to have them all run in parallel, since I don’t think Cypress is designed to be run in multiple processes at the same time on one machine. I came across this blog post, found it help you out? https://ronnie.dev/2020/05/16/parallel-cypress-tests/